# Reference Request: Eberhard Zeidler's missing volume.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

Eberhard Zeidler has an excellent exposition on nonlinear functional analysis titled as *Nonlinear Functional Analysis and its Applications*. It is an exposition subdivided into 5 volumes containing 100 chapters in total. However, I am unable to locate the 5th volume anywhere. The contents of the last volume is mentioned in his first volume and uptil the fourth volume, it is mentioned that the fifth volume is available. However, I cannot locate it anywhere.

Does anyone know if it exists and where can I locate it?

Comment: @daw 2a and 2b are written to be one volume. Here are multiple reasons why: Each volume contains an appendix but 2a doesn't; neither it contains a list of symbols, index, bibliography etc. Moreover, the content of each volume is written out in the first, but the content attributed to 5th isn't present in any volume. Lastly, the fourth volume mentions, in the preface, that applications to physics will be covered in this volume and the following part V. So I believe there is supposed to be part 5, that is separate from 1,2a,2b,3,4.

Comment: Also, there are supposed to be 100 chapters in total, as per the preface of the first volume, but the volume 4 ends at Chapter 79 so Chapter 80-100 is supposed to be present inside volume 5.

Comment: Part V indeed doesn't seem to exists. It's not listed on MathSciNet, and I can find no traces of it elsewhere either. [This obituary](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10013-018-00332-4) mentions the other parts as “an expanded 5 volume English edition”, and say that his QFT text was unfinished at the time of his death, but nothing about the missing part V.

Comment: @HansLundmark Jost writes "but a greatly expanded and largely rewritten English 4-volume version", I think you have a typo in the comment

Comment: here is another obituary https://doi.org/10.1365/s13291-017-0175-4  - no mention of the missing volume

Comment: @s.harp: No, in the link I gave, the HTML version says “He went on to found the field of nonlinear functional analysis with his impressive books, first in German and later in an expanded 5 volume English edition “*Nonlinear Functional Analysis and its Applications*” [1,2,3,4,5].” And the PDF version says the same, except that the citation is written as “[1–5]”.

Comment: @Hans oh wow, I had the _other_ obituary (also written by Jost) open, and there the quote was as I wrote it (calling it a 4-volume version). It seems he wrote two different obituaries..

Comment: @s.harp: I see. Anyway, no matter how one counts those five books, it's seems clear that there is no volume V.